# Using an array for the Body in Send-MailMessage

Tags: powershell

I have a small script that looks through AD and finds user's EmployeeID numbers. But  When attempting to send mail then I am getting an error message like below.

error message :

```
Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Specified method is not supported.
At line:53 char:93
+ ... maddress -Body ($expiredaccounts) -BodyAsHtml
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

here is my code :

```
$expiredaccounts = Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -TimeSpan 30.00:00:00 | Where-Object { $_.Enabled -eq $true } 
$expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName, AccountExpirationDate, @{Name='EmployeeID';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties employeeID).employeeID}}, @{Name='EmployeeID2';Expression={($_ |Get-ADUser -Properties pager).pager}} |  ConvertTo-Html | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -to $emailto -Subject $subject -SmtpServer $smtp -From $fromaddress -Body ($expiredaccounts) -BodyAsHtml
```

Comment: The line `$expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName ...` isn't doing anything useful.  You need to change it to something like this: `$accountsHTML = $expiredaccounts | Select-Object name, SamAccountName ...`, then use `$accountsHTML` in the `-Body` parameter.

Comment: Either that, or assign the results back to the same variable `$expiredaccounts = $expiredaccounts | ...`